# Castle Windsor - Container.Dispose() results in a Dispose() method being called twice

Tags: castle-windsor

I have two classes, with one being injected with another:-

```
public class A : IClassA
{
    public A(IClassB b)
    {
       ...
    }
}

public class B : IClassB, IDisposable
{
   ...
}
```

And they are registered like this:-

```
container.Register(Component.For<IClassA>().ImplementedBy<A>().LifeStyle.Singleton);
container.Register(Component.For<IClassB>().ImplementedBy<B>().LifeStyle.Transient);
```

When I close my application I call `Container.Dispose()`. At this point I find that the `Dispose()` method of class "B" is called twice. If I register class "B" as a *singleton* then it only gets called once. Why is this?

I'm using Castle Windsor v3.3.0.

Here are the call stacks from the two calls to Dispose(), if that helps (I've truncated them at the point where I call `Container.Dispose()`).

First call to Dispose():

> Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.LifecycleConcerns.DisposalConcern.Apply(Castle.Core.ComponentModel model, object component) Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.ApplyConcerns(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable steps, object instance)  Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.ApplyDecommissionConcerns(object instance)  Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalDestroy(object instance) Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Destroy(object instance)    Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.Release(object instance)   Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ReleaseCore(Castle.MicroKernel.Burden burden) Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Release(Castle.MicroKernel.Burden burden)    Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Burden.Release()  Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Releasers.LifecycledComponentsReleasePolicy.Dispose() Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.Internal.TypedFactoryInterceptor.Dispose()    Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.LifecycleConcerns.DisposalConcern.Apply(Castle.Core.ComponentModel model, object component)   Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.ApplyConcerns(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable steps, object instance)  Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.ApplyDecommissionConcerns(object instance)  Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalDestroy(object instance) Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Destroy(object instance)    Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.Release(object instance)   Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ReleaseCore(Castle.MicroKernel.Burden burden) Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Release(Castle.MicroKernel.Burden burden)    Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Burden.Release()  Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Releasers.LifecycledComponentsReleasePolicy.Dispose() Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.DisposeComponentsInstancesWithinTracker()   Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Dispose()   Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Dispose()    Unknown

Second call to Dispose():

> Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.LifecycleConcerns.DisposalConcern.Apply(Castle.Core.ComponentModel model, object component) Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.ApplyConcerns(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable steps, object instance)  Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.ApplyDecommissionConcerns(object instance)  Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalDestroy(object instance) Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Destroy(object instance)    Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.Release(object instance)   Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ReleaseCore(Castle.MicroKernel.Burden burden) Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Release(Castle.MicroKernel.Burden burden)    Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Burden.Release()  Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Burden.Release.AnonymousMethod__0(Castle.MicroKernel.Burden c)    Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.Generic.List.ForEach(System.Action action)    Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Burden.Release()  Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.SingletonLifestyleManager.Dispose() Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Dispose() Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.DisposeHandler(Castle.MicroKernel.IHandler handler) Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.DisposeHandlers()   Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Dispose()   Unknown
>       Castle.Windsor.dll!Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Dispose()    Unknown

Comment: Does that also happen with latest Windsor version?

Comment: What is the behaviour if you call `Release()` for the instance of `B`? (Windsor may be expecting that you have explicitly called `Release` for transient instances)

Comment: @PhilDegenhardt nope, calling `container.Dispose()` should just do the trick.

Comment: This looks like it might be a bug... if it still happens in the latest version you might want to report it https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/issues

Comment: @KrzysztofKozmic updating the package is going to cause a few headaches so it'll be a while before I can do this. I can fix it by registering class "B" as a singleton, which won't cause any problems in this scenario. I'll also see if I can create a standalone repro, which I can then test with the latest version.

Comment: @KrzysztofKozmic FYI I've just created a repro and tested with later versions of Windsor. The bug was still present in 4.0.0 but appears to be fixed in 4.1.0 onwards.

Comment: Ah yes, could be this https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/pull/344